# How to use double colon in Stream.collect for HashMap?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to read a csv file into a hashmap by using the first column as a key, the second column as a value, and ignoring the third column.

I wrote the following code and it works. I would like to know how to rewrite the syntax with double colon "::".

I check the API docs, but most of examples are using List instead of Map.

I used a string to mock a csv file: "A,1,!","B,2,@","C,3,#","D,4,$","E,5,%"

```
Map<String,String> maps = Stream.of("A,1,!","B,2,@","C,3,#","D,4,$","E,5,%")
      .collect(() -> new HashMap<String,String>(),
               (map, line) -> {String x[] = line.split(","); map.put(x[0],x[1]);},
               (map1, map2) -> map1.putAll(map2));
System.out.println(maps);
```

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing here? It seems to be not the best way how you do it... I would like to provide a better way.

Comment: Uh, Java 8's lambdas and streams are nice features, but for this use case the "old" way is much more readable imho

Comment: Because in the JAVA API, they alway use List in double colon examples. I just wonder if double colon can be used in Map.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would do this:

```
Map<String, String> maps = Stream.of("A,1,!", "B,2,@", "C,3,#", "D,4,$", "E,5,%").
        map(line -> line.split(",")).
        collect(HashMap::new, (map, line) -> map.put(line[0], line[1]), HashMap::putAll);
```

i.e. separate out the logic into distinct stream transformation operations. Doing the `map` in the `collect` clouds the intent of the code.

Comment: You could replace "(line)" with "line" (SO won't let me do that without finding something else to edit).

Comment: Could you explain what the intent of the code is? The OP is not reacting yet and I'd like to give it a try aswell.

Comment: @skiwi As I understand it the OP has a flat file with some number of lines. On each line there are a number of comma-delimited tokens. The OP wants to create a `Map` where the key is the first token and the value is the second.

Comment: @BoristheSpider And the third token just gets ignored? If so then I did understand it since the beginning, but I didn't think that could be correct.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think you want to be using the concrete `collect()` with the supplier, accumulator and combiner.
You should rely more on higher level methods, this becomes then:

```
Map<String, String> map = Stream.of("A,1,!","B,2,@","C,3,#","D,4,$","E,5,%")
        .map(line -> line.split(","))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                array -> array[0],
                array -> array[1]
        ));
```

Which does the following:

1. Create a `Stream<String>`.
2. Map it to a `Stream<String[]>`.
3. Collect the results via a `Collectors.toMap` which takes a key mapper and a value mapper as arguments.

   1. Here I map the `array` to `array[0]` for the key.
   2. Here I map the `array` to `array[1]` for the value.

Then to confirm it works I print:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key = " + k + " / Value = " + v));
```

Which gives:

> Key = A / Value = 1
>   Key = B / Value = 2
>   Key = C / Value = 3
>   Key = D / Value = 4
>   Key = E / Value = 5